# Problem performing segue with Firebase Auth and Realtime Database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I need to perform a segue by reading a value in Realtime Database using Firebase to handle roles.

I'm making an iOS app using Firebase. I did the authentication with Firebase Auth using Email/Password method. My app has 2 segues: the first called 'inicio' and the other one called 'inicio2'. In Realtime DB i'm saving users with email, userID and a boolean attribute called 'isAdmin'. The problem is that i need to perform a segue at login process depending on 'isAdmin' value. `if isAdmin == false`, i need to perform segue 'inicio'; `if isAdmin == true`, i need to perform segue 'inicio2'. Here is the code that i'm trying:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase

class InicioSesionViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var correo: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!

var ref: DatabaseReference!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref = Database.database().reference()

    correo.text = ""
    password.text = ""

    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("ocultarTeclado")))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

//MARK: ViewDidAppear().
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    correo.text = ""
    password.text = ""
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    sesionActiva()
}

@IBAction func ingresar(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if correo.text != "" && password.text != "" {
        guard let email = correo.text else { return }
        guard let contraseña = password.text else { return }
        inicioSesion(correo: email, pass: contraseña)
    } else {
        let alerta = UIAlertController(title: "Atención", message: "Ingrese correo electrónico y contraseña.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let aceptar = UIAlertAction(title: "Aceptar", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alerta.addAction(aceptar)
        present(alerta, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func inicioSesion(correo: String, pass: String){
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: correo, password: pass){ (user, error) in
        if user != nil {
            self.ref.child("users").childByAutoId().observe(DataEventType.value) { (snapshot) in
                let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                let admin = value?["isAdmin"] as? Bool

                if admin == false {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "inicio", sender: self)
                    print("Entró")
                } else {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "inicio2", sender: self)
                    print("Entró")
                }
            }
        } else {
            if let error = error?.localizedDescription {
                print("Error en Firebase", error)
            } else {
                print("Error en el código")
            }

            let alerta = UIAlertController(title: "Atención", message: "Se produjo un error al iniciar sesión. Verifique que el correo electrónico y la contraseña sean correctas.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let aceptar = UIAlertAction(title: "Aceptar", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alerta.addAction(aceptar)
            self.present(alerta, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

//Función para ocultar teclado en cualquier parte de la vista.
@objc func ocultarTeclado(){
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

//Comprueba si la sesion estaba iniciada.
func sesionActiva(){
    Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, error) in
        if error == nil {
            print("No estamos logueados")
        } else {
            print("Si estamos logueados")
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "inicio", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Actually, only performs 'inicio' segue.

Comment: I don't understand you exactly, what you mean is that you always enter the segue called 'inicio' is correct?, If so, make sure the administrator is, 'inicio' or 'inicio2'?

Comment: No. For the users saved in Database, i need to recognize if isAdmin is true or false. If isAdmin == false, the app has to perform segue 'inicio'. If isAdmin == true, has to perform segue 'inicio2'.

Comment: Sometimes it's best to look at the simplest items.  If youre able to perform a segue, but not the right now.
Are you sure the isAdmin value is being saved and read correctly?  I'd start by checking the value that you're getting for admin, and make sure that the user is actually an admin and you're able to read it as a bool.